# checkbox change event record penalty or discount jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cf5cuy1f/1/)***

I am trying to get a penalty or discount depending on the quarter chosen and the current quarter. For example user choose first quarter since it long passed there will be penalty. Basically if the quarter is passed there will be penalty. My question is like this. How to make it in a way that the values will persist and not disappear example we go on and click first quarter there will be a penalty and if user clicks on second quarter the penalty will accumulate. Since its currently in third quarter there should be a discount which is happening but the penalty is lost. I want the penalty to persist. How is this possible.

```js
$('table#table').on('change', 'tr input:checkbox.quarter', function() {
  var checked = $(this).closest('tr').find('input:checkbox.quarter:checked').length;
  var value = $(this).closest('tr').find('input.quarter').val();
  var date = new Date();
  var quarter = parseInt(date.getMonth() / 3) + 1;
  var quaeternow = quarter;
  var tax = (value * checked).toFixed(2);
  var discount = 0;
  var penalty = 0;
  console.log(quaeternow);
  if (checked) {
    if (checked >= quaeternow) {
      //alert('discount');
      discount = (tax * .1).toFixed(2);
      //penalty = 0;
    } else {
      //alert('interes');
      //discount=0;
      penalty = (tax * .02).toFixed(2);

    }

    $('#div').append('discount ' + discount + '</br>');
    $('#div').append('penalty ' + penalty + '</br></br>');
    console.log(discount);
    console.log(penalty);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='table'>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <center>
        <input type="checkbox" value="75" id1="1stqtr" id="9/29/2015" class="quarter">first quarter</center>
    </td>
    <td>
      <center>
        <input type="checkbox" value="75" id1="2ndqtr" id="9/29/2015" class="quarter">second quarter</center>
    </td>
    <td>
      <center>
        <input type="checkbox" value="75" id1="3rdqtr" id="9/29/2015" class="quarter">third quarter</center>
    </td>
    <td>
      <center>
        <input type="checkbox" value="75" id1="4thqtr" id="9/29/2015" class="quarter">fourth quarter</center>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id='div'></div>
```

Comment: why there are same `id` for all the `checkbox`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qcbm0cfg/2/ ?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao i fix will that i didn't see that on i will change it to `data attr`

Comment: @ArunPJohny i will check again the computation i make the result is a bit different `my calculation i think is a bit off`

Comment: @ArunPJohny can you please explain a bit i been trying to understand the code for a while now but i cant seem to get how you made it.

Comment: @Pekka which part of the code?

Comment: @ArunPJohny `+$(this).attr('id1').match(/^\d+/),` what is `+` for `$(this).data('discount', dis).data('penalty', pen);` i been trying to check this in dev tools i cant find it. This should be in the checkbox since `$(this)` referes to checked checkbox i cant find it. also `if (this.checked)` what is the difference between `if ($(this).checked)`

Comment: @Pekka that is the [unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) operator... to convert the returning string to a number

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90945/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-pekka).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form what I understand, you could do something like

```js
var discount = 0;
var penalty = 0;
var quarter = parseInt(new Date().getMonth() / 3) + 1;

$('#table').on('change', 'input.quarter:checkbox', function() {
  var cquater = +$(this).attr('id1').match(/^\d+/),
    tax = +this.value,
    dis,
    pen;

  if (cquater < quarter) {
    pen = tax * .02;
    dis = 0;
  } else {
    dis = tax * .1;
    pen = 0;
  }
  if (this.checked) {
    penalty += pen;
    discount += dis;
  } else {
    penalty -= pen;
    discount -= dis;
  }

  $('#div').append('discount ' + discount + '</br>');
  $('#div').append('penalty ' + penalty + '</br></br>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='table'>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <center>
        <input type="checkbox" value="75" id1="1stqtr" id="9/29/2015" class="quarter">first quarter</center>
    </td>
    <td>
      <center>
        <input type="checkbox" value="75" id1="2ndqtr" id="9/29/2015" class="quarter">second quarter</center>
    </td>
    <td>
      <center>
        <input type="checkbox" value="75" id1="3rdqtr" id="9/29/2015" class="quarter">third quarter</center>
    </td>
    <td>
      <center>
        <input type="checkbox" value="75" id1="4thqtr" id="9/29/2015" class="quarter">fourth quarter</center>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id='div'></div>
```

Comment: arun i have one question what if there are multiple row. my problem is the pen and dis is being shared i mean it is increasing. how can i make it in a way that the var dis and pen should only be used in its respective row only.

Comment: that was so simple that i missed it i was concentrating on making different variables for each row. the fiddle works great.